# AlamofireImage GrayImageEffect

Tags: image, swift, alamofire

I was make a request to a image view from url whit AlamofireImage.
I revice the image but i want to convert this image in grayscale.
I write a simple class who transform the image in gray scale but how i transform the image form alamofire to gray scale. 
I try this method but don´t work

```
            cell.imagem.af_setImageWithURLRequest(self.imageRequest(artwork.thumbnail), placeholderImage: nil, filter: nil, imageTransition: UIImageView.ImageTransition.None, completion: { (_, _, imageResult) -> Void in
            if imageResult.isSuccess {
                cell.imagem.image = nil
                cell.imagem.image = imageResult.value?.grayScaleImage()
            }
        })
```

and my class to transform image to gray scale is:

```
func grayScaleImage() -> UIImage {
    let imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

    let width = Int(self.size.width)
    let height = Int(self.size.height)
    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, 8, 0, colorSpace, .allZeros);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, self.CGImage!);

    let imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef!)
    return newImage
}}
```

Comment: You should instead create a grayScale [ImageFilter](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage/blob/master/Source/ImageFilter.swift#L34-L40) and use that in the `filter` parameter to allow you to convert to grayscale asynchronously. Right now you're converting it on the main thread.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36537963/how-do-i-apply-a-custom-filter that should be what you need.